# ¿Php mailer como configurar?

Tags: php, phpmailer

estoy empezando a usar la documentación de `PHPMailer` pero no se como enlazarla a mi correo, acabo de descargar la versión mas reciente de `PHPmailer` y mi versión de `PHP` en mi ÌIS`es la 5.6.31, mi código de`PHP` es el siguiente.

```
<?php

require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();

if( isset( $_POST['template-contactform-submit'] ) AND $_POST['template-contactform-submit'] == 'submit' ) {
    if( $_POST['template-contactform-name'] != '' AND $_POST['template-contactform-email'] != '' AND $_POST['template-contactform-message'] != '' ) {

        $name = $_POST['template-contactform-name'];
        $email = $_POST['template-contactform-email'];
        $phone = $_POST['template-contactform-phone'];
        $service = $_POST['template-contactform-service'];
        $subject = $_POST['template-contactform-subject'];
        $message = $_POST['template-contactform-message'];

        $subject = isset($subject) ? $subject : 'New Message From Contact Form';

        $botcheck = $_POST['template-contactform-botcheck'];

        $toemail = 'mancha-94@hotmail.com'; // Your Email Address
        $toname = 'Polo Moreno'; // Your Name

        if( $botcheck == '' ) {

            $mail->SetFrom( $email , $name );
            $mail->AddReplyTo( $email , $name );
            $mail->AddAddress( $toemail , $toname );
            $mail->Subject = $subject;

            $name = isset($name) ? "Name: $name<br><br>" : '';
            $email = isset($email) ? "Email: $email<br><br>" : '';
            $phone = isset($phone) ? "Phone: $phone<br><br>" : '';
            $service = isset($service) ? "Service: $service<br><br>" : '';
            $message = isset($message) ? "Message: $message<br><br>" : '';

            $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? '<br><br><br>This Form was submitted from: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

            $body = "$name $email $phone $service $message $referrer";

            $mail->MsgHTML( $body );
            $sendEmail = $mail->Send();

            if( $sendEmail == true ):
                echo 'We have <strong>successfully</strong> received your Message and will get Back to you as soon as possible.';
            else:
                echo 'Email <strong>could not</strong> be sent due to some Unexpected Error. Please Try Again later.<br /><br /><strong>Reason:</strong><br />' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '';
            endif;
        } else {
            echo 'Bot <strong>Detected</strong>.! Clean yourself Botster.!';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Please <strong>Fill up</strong> all the Fields and Try Again.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'An <strong>unexpected error</strong> occured. Please Try Again later.';
}

?>
```

Que es lo que esta mal con mi ¿código? ya que no quiere ejecutar el enviar el mensaje a mi correo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo siempre que he usado `PHPMailer` de dejado configurado tanto el smtp, como la cuenta con la que se envia el correo con su clave.

Las líneas son:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//Enable SMTP debugging. 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               
//Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.
$mail->isSMTP();            
//Set SMTP host name                          
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
//Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          
//Provide username and password     
$mail->Username = "name@gmail.com";                 
$mail->Password = "super_secret_password";                           
//If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                           
//Set TCP port to connect to 
$mail->Port = 587;
```

Comprueba la configuración de `Hotmail`, y prueba con esto

Comment: ¡FUNCIONO! muchas gracias ! ¿donde puedo aprender mas del como usar el PHPMailer?

Comment: Yo todo ha sido viendo ejemplos pir google. Me alegro que te funcione

Comment: como lo pongo a funcionar en un servidor de paga?

Comment: Buenas @alejandro esta pregunta es de hace 9 meses, abre tu propia pregunta, gracias.